Symfony 7.2 Notifier Component Testing I can test sending only "sync" but not "async" messages using NotifierInterface service
Let's start with the fact that everything works fine but when it comes to tests I can test not everything.
When I use "NotifierInterface" service for sending "async" messages everything works
But when it comes to tests, I don't know why, but my tests don't see "async" messages were sent by "NotifierInterface" service
In contrast to that when I use "ChatterInterface" service for sending messages it works and tests fine.
FIRST SCENARIO: That doesn't pass the test.
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

// I didn't include all the necessary namespaces :)

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/')]
    public function home(
        NotifierInterface $notifier,
    ) {
        $subject = 'Symfony Notifier';
        $content = 'Message!';
        
        $notification = new Notification(
            subject: $subject,
            channels: [
                'chat/telegram',
            ],
        );
        $notification
            ->content($content)
            ->emoji('')
        ;
        
        $recipient = new Recipient(
            email: $adminEmail,
            phone: $adminPhone,
        );
        
        $notifier->send(
            $notification,
            $recipient,
        );
        
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }
}

SECOND SCENARIO: That passes the test.
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

// I didn't include all the necessary namespaces :)

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/')]
    public function home(
        ?ChatterInterface $chatter,
    ) {
        
        $telegramOptions = new TelegramOptions();

        $telegramMessage = (new ChatMessage('Hello, it is a new message'))
            ->transport('telegram')
            ->options($telegramOptions)
        ;

        if (null !== $chatter) {
            $chatter->send($telegramMessage);
        }
        
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }
}

TEST
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Application\Controller;

// I didn't include all the necessary namespaces :)

class HomeControllerTest extends AbstractApplicationCase {
    
    public function testNotifierOneAsyncMessengeWasSent() {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->followRedirects(true);
        
        // request to the controller method where I make async notification
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
        
        $event = $this->getNotifierEvent(); // null for FIRST SCENARIO
        $notification = $this->getNotifierMessage(); // null for FIRST SCENARIO
        
        //###> ASSERT ###
        // $this->assertQueuedNotificationCount(1); // act same as below
        $this->assertQueuedNotificationCount(1, 'telegram');
        /** for FIRST SCENARIO
          * Failed asserting that the Transport telegram has queued "1" emails (0 queued).
          │
          │ C:\Workspace\SYMFONY\__SANDBOX__\drafts\vendor\symfony\framework-
          | bundle\Test\NotificationAssertionsTrait.php:32
          │ C:\Workspace\SYMFONY\__SANDBOX__\drafts\tests\Application\Controller\HomeControllerTest.php:29
          │ C:\Workspace\SYMFONY\__SANDBOX__\drafts\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:104
         */

        if ($event instanceof MessageEvent) {
            $this->assertNotificationIsQueued($event);            
        }
        
        if ($notification instanceof MessageInterface) {
            $this->assertNotificationSubjectContains($notification, 'Hello');
            $this->assertNotificationTransportIsEqual($notification, 'telegram');
        }
        //###< ASSERT ###
    }
}

config/notifier.yaml
when@test: &test
    framework:
        notifier:

            chatter_transports:
                telegram:       'null://null'

framework:
    notifier:
        message_bus: messenger.default_bus
        
        chatter_transports:
            telegram:           '%env(TELEGRAM_DSN)%'

        channel_policy:
            urgent:
            -   'browser'
            
            high:
            -   'browser'
            
            medium:
            -   'browser'
            
            low:
            -   'browser'

        admin_recipients:
            -   email:                '%env(APP_ADMIN_EMAIL)%'
                phone:                '%env(APP_ADMIN_PHONE)%'

config/messenger.yaml
framework:
    messenger:

        transports:
            sync: 'sync://'
            
            async:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                    queue_name: async
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 3
                    delay: 3000
                    multiplier: 2
                    max_delay: 10000

        routing:
            # NOTIFIER
            'Symfony\Component\Notifier\*': async

